# Best way to make a copy of an Oracle database using only SQL shell

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to make a copy of a schema in an Oracle Database with a slightly different name.

I can do this pretty easily with MSS with something like:

```
BACKUP DATABASE {DATABASE_NAME} TO DISK='{DIRECTORY}\{BACKUP_NAME}'
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = '{DIRECTORY}\{BACKUP_NAME}'
RESTORE DATABASE {NEW_DATABASE} FROM DISK = '{DIRECTORY}\{BACKUP_NAME}' WITH MOVE '{mdf}' TO '{DIRECTORY}\{mdf}.mdf', MOVE '{ldf}' TO '{DIRECTORY}\{ldf}.ldf'
```

Is there any equivalent for Oracle DB?

For reference, I'm connecting to the database with full privileges using JBDC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSS uses "database" to refer to several different concepts in Oracle. I think maybe you mean that you want to export one *schema* and re-import it into the same Oracle database with a different schema name. I would normally use **datapump** from the command line for this (expdp/impdp). However, [there is a datapump API](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g#DataPumpAPI) that you can use to do this from a SQL shell.

```
-- export
declare
  l_dp_handle       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_dp_handle := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open('EXPORT','SCHEMA',null,'MY_EXPORT','LATEST');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(l_dp_handle,'my_export.dmp','DATA_PUMP_DIR');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(l_dp_handle,'my_export.log','DATA_PUMP_DIR',null,DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_filter(l_dp_handle,'SCHEMA_EXPR','= ''OLD_SCHEMA_NAME''');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job(l_dp_handle);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.detach(l_dp_handle);
END;
/

-- check status with:
select * from dba_datapump_jobs;

-- import 
declare
  l_dp_handle       NUMBER;
BEGIN
  l_dp_handle := DBMS_DATAPUMP.open('IMPORT','SCHEMA',null,'MY_IMPORT','LATEST');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(l_dp_handle,'my_export.dmp','DATA_PUMP_DIR');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.add_file(l_dp_handle,'my_export.imp.log','DATA_PUMP_DIR',null,DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_LOG_FILE);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_filter(l_dp_handle,'SCHEMA_EXPR','= ''OLD_SCHEMA_NAME''');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.metadata_remap(l_dp_handle,'REMAP_SCHEMA','OLD_SCHEMA_NAME','NEW_SCHEMA_NAME');
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.start_job(l_dp_handle);
  DBMS_DATAPUMP.detach(l_dp_handle);
END;
/
```

Note that you'll need DBA privileges if you want to import into a schema other than your own. Your Oracle user will also need read/write privileges on the directory (DATA_PUMP_DIR in this example), execute privileges on DBMS_DATAPUMP, etc.

Comment: I *think* this is exactly what I want. I'm going to try it.

Comment: For the first add_file line, I'm told I'm giving an invalid argument value. This is what I'm doing: DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE(l_dp_handle, '{dbBackup.ToLower()}.dmp', '{DbDumpDir}'); where dbBackup is the name of the backup, and DbDumpDir is a path to the database dump. Any idea what mistake I'm making?

Comment: @Damien - you have to pass the name of an Oracle directory object, not an OS directory path. Look in `all_directories` to see if you have access to any. You may need extra privileges (for this, and to create the new user).

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go.

Comment: My company decided what I was working on was ridiculous, and I've now moved to a new project. Regardless, I'm sure this would have worked, so I'm marking it as correct.